# display mutiple google maps on a single page with data from MySQL and using loop

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I want to display multiple google maps with my latitude and longitude from MySQL and I use looping. Here is my code:

```
    <style>         
        .my_map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <div>
        <?php
            foreach($clinics AS $clinic) {
        ?>
                <div class="my_map" id="map_<?php print($clinic->id); ?>" >
                    <script>
                        var map;

                        function initMap() {
                            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_<?php print($clinic->id); ?>'), {
                                    center: {lat: <?php print($clinic->latitude); ?>, lng: <?php print($clinic->longitude); ?>},
                                    zoom: 16
                            });
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </div>


    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

My problem is only the last map is displayed while the others before do not render the maps. Should I not write the script inside the loop? Thanks.

Comment: The script should never be written in loop. Rather the marker needs to be in loop.please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480105/how-to-show-multiple-areas-by-location-in-google-maps-using-php and modify codes as required. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not tested I'd suggest an approach similar to this perhaps. Create a javascript variable with all the original data from the php variable `$clinics` - in this case json - and use the `initMap` function to iterate through that variable/data, creating a map object on each iteration.

```
<style>         
    .my_map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"></script>
<script>

    var obj,map;

    <?php

        /*
            assuming that `$clinics` is an array and that each member is also an array
            with constituent keys id,latitude,longitude which is how it appears to be 
            from the original question

            encode as json data
        */
        $json=json_encode( $clinics );

        /* create javascript variable with data */
        echo "
            var json={$json};
        ";

    ?>
    function initMap(){
        /* iterate through json data */
        for( var n in json ){
            obj=json[n];
            map=new google.maps.Map( document.querySelector('div[ data-id="'+n+'" ]'),{
                center:{ lat:parseFloat( obj.latitude ), lng:parseFloat( obj.longitude ) },
                zoom:16
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
    /*
        generate containers to hold each map based upon original array
    */
    foreach( $clinics as $index => $clinic ){
        echo "<div class='my_map' data-id='{$index}'></div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use  `foreach  .. : end foreach` eg:

```
<div>
      <?php  foreach($clinics AS $clinic) :   ?>
              <div class="my_map" id="map_<?php print($clinic->id); ?>" >
                  <script>
                      var map;

                      function initMap() {
                          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_<?php print($clinic->id); ?>'), {
                                  center: {lat: <?php print($clinic->latitude); ?>, lng: <?php print($clinic->longitude); ?>},
                                  zoom: 16
                          });
                      }
                  </script>
              </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We tried the code suggested by RamRaider however we were unable to get the maps showing. To get it working we had to attach the initialise script call to end of the page. The code therefore becomes:

```
<style>         
    .my_map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        // Asynchronously Load the map API
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });

    var obj,map;

    <?php

        /*
            assuming that `$clinics` is an array and that each member is also an array
            with constituent keys id,latitude,longitude which is how it appears to be 
            from the original question

            encode as json data
        */
        $json=json_encode( $clinics );

        /* create javascript variable with data */
        echo "
            var json={$json};
        ";

    ?>
    function initMap(){
        /* iterate through json data */
        for( var n in json ){
            obj=json[n];
            map=new google.maps.Map( document.querySelector('div[ data-id="'+n+'" ]'),{
                center:{ lat:parseFloat( obj.latitude ), lng:parseFloat( obj.longitude ) },
                zoom:16
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
    /*
        generate containers to hold each map based upon original array
    */
    foreach( $clinics as $index => $clinic ){
        echo "<div class='my_map' data-id='{$index}'></div>";
    }
?>
```